# Custom Field URL + description

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to make some post with has many URLs with descriptions attached to it, the ACF has the URL module wich is fine, I can add many URLs as needed but I need to add a description to each of this field (vinculated, not a separated text field), how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a Repeater field, if you have [the Pro version](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/)?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have the pro version, It's an slightly old WP site so the actual version might not work.

Comment: I'm sure they'd give you the pro version to match the version you're already running if you ask. But there are probably other ways to do this, sure.